# Как мне реализовать select в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Пытаюсь понять как работает `select` вместе с `react`+`redux`. Не пойму как мне изменять `state` по событию `handleChange`, тоесть записать выбранный параметр, так как он может быть только один? Кто то может объяснить?

Детальный пример кода [тут](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqqqo64y3w)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select/Select";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl/FormControl";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem/MenuItem";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectRender: [
      {
        title: "Title 1",
        value: ""
      },
      {
        title: "Title 2",
        value: ""
      },
      {
        title: "Title 3",
        value: ""
      }
    ]
  };
  handleChange = index => event => {
    this.setState({
      selectValue: {
        ...this.state.selectRender,
        [index]: event.target.value
      }
    });
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(index);
  };
  render() {
    const renderSelect = this.state.selectRender.map((item, index) => (
      <FormControl key={index} style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "27px" }}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-auto-width">{item.title}</InputLabel>
        <Select
          id={item.index}
          value={this.state.selectRender[item.value]}
          onChange={this.handleChange(item.index)}
          inputProps={{
            name: "selectValue"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="kilograms">Kilograms</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="meters">Meters</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="minutes">Minutes</MenuItem>
        </Select>
        value: {item.value}
      </FormControl>
    ));
    return <div className="App">{renderSelect}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import React from 'react';

const onChange = (input: WrappedFieldInputProps) => (event) =>
  input.onChange(event.target.value);

export const SelectField = ({ input, meta: { touched, error }, children, ...custom }: ISelectFieldProps) => {
  return (
<FormControl error={touched && error}>
  <InputLabel htmlFor={'input-id'}>{'Label'}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    error={touched && error}
    {...input}
    input={<Input name={input.name} id={'input-id'} />}
    onChange={onChange(input)}
    children={children}
    {...custom}
  />
  {touched && error && <FormHelperText>{error}</FormHelperText>}
</FormControl>
  );
};
```

Исплоьзование:

```js
export const ProjectFieldJsx: React.StatelessComponent<IProjectFieldProps> = ({
  className,
  name,
}) => (
  <Field name={name} component={SelectField} className={className} label={'Label'}>
<MenuItem value={'value1'}>
  Label1
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={'value2'}>
  Label2
</MenuItem>
  </Field>
);
```